# Ubuntu 20.04 occasionally freezes

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, nvidia, freeze

I've a brand new Dell XPS 15 laptop, in which I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 and Nvidia drivers 450.80. Recently (since a month) my system completely freezes (once a week at least) and none of the techniques I've read about it worked in order to "unfreeze" or to reboot the OS (like REISUB). Sad story I've always to hard power off from the main button.

Each time something like that happens I try to look at `journalctl` output from previous session and I cannot see any errors. I've tried to generally look in the `/var/log/` folder and grep with the specific time my GUI freezes but nothing to do. I cannot understand where this problem comes from.

I've thought about CUDA drivers since after installing them I've started to notice this behaviour. However, I am not completely sure since other applications have been installed too. Can someone driving me on the right direction? I don't really know where to put my hands. Thank you.